# Why can I not assign to this generic variable?

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes, nested-generics

I'm trying to implement a tree such that the nodes are generic:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<U extends BinarySearchTree.Node, T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
{
    public U root;
    ...

    public class Node {
        T data;
        U left;
        U right;

        public Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to do an assignment in one of my methodsI get a "Expected U but found BinarySearchTree.Node:

```
public void display(U root) {
    if (root != null) {
        display(root.left); // gives compile time error
        System.out.print(" " + root.data);
        display(root.right); // gives compile time error
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the place of display method?

Answer (score 2):

Since `Node` is not static, every `Node` instance belongs to a containing `BinarySearchTree` instance. But it is not possible with generics to specify to which one it belongs. So if you specify `BinarySearchTree.Node` it can belong to any `BinarySearchTree`. Since you also used a raw type (don't ignore the warnings!) it is not known what `U` is. Therefore, Java cannot check that `root.left` and `root.right` are of the same type, which is why you get the error.

You can fix the compile error by specifying the class as follows:

```
class BinarySearchTree<U extends BinarySearchTree<U,T>.Node, T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
{ ... }
```

but this does not fix the underlying problem that the nodes can belong to any containing `BinarySearchTree`, which probably is not what you want.

If you really want use a generic node type, you could make it static you, so that it doesn't belong to containing instances anymore:

```
public static class Node<U,T> 
{
    ...
}
```

But I question the need to have a generic node class in the first place. Usually, such nodes are considered an implementation detail and you want to have full control over creating them from within your class. That cannot work with a generic node because your class doesn't know what kind of nodes to instantiate.

So I would define your `BinarySearchTree` class as follows:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
{
    private Node<T> root;

    private static class Node<T> 
    {
        T data;
        Node<T> left;
        Node<T> right;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: The reason is that I need to subclass the BinarySearchTree class and add an int member to its node (seperate from the data field)

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite the class definition to

```
public class BinarySearchTree<U extends BinarySearchTree<U, T>.Node, T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```